# how to use zed camera without zed-ros-wrapper package

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i cant use this package as it requires cuda and i do not have nvidia GPU in my laptop, please help me im new to ros. thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347054/how-to-use-zed-camera-without-zed-ros-wrapper-package/) by [hy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52662/hy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't a ROS question...

but: https://support.stereolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/207776845-Can-I-use-the-ZED-without-CUDA-

You cannot use the ZED SDK (for which all ROS wrapped drivers will use) without a GPU. It is a strict requirement.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52662/hy/) on 2020-03-20**:
i dont want to use ZED SDK, i am asking for alternative ROS package by which i can get right and left camera unrectified images to use these topics with my own algorithm.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-20**:
Doesn't the page which @stevemacenski links already explain how to do that?

> The ZED camera is UVC (Universal Video Class) compliant so you can capture the left and right video streams of the ZED on Windows, Linux and even OSX without the ZED SDK.